# Dynamic Memory Allocation in fast RAM

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory-management

On a Windows 32-bit and 64-bit machine, I have to allocate memory to store large amounts of data that are streaming live, a total of around 1GB. If I use malloc(), I am going to obtain a virtual memory address, and this address could be actually causing some paging to the hard drive depending on the amount of memory I have. Unfortunately I'm afraid that the HD will impact performance and cause data to be missing.

Is there a way to force memory to allocate only in RAM, even if it means that I get an error when not enough memory is available (so the user needs to close other things or use another machine)? I want to guarantee that all operations will be done in memory. If this fails, forcing the application to exit is acceptable.

I know that another process may come in and itself take some memory, but I am not worried because in this machine that is not happening (it'll be the only application on the machine to be doing this large allocation).

[Edit:]
My attempt so far has been to try use VirtualLock as follows:

```
if(!SetProcessWorkingSetSize(this, 300000, 300008))
    printf("Error Changing Working Set Size\n");

// Allocate 1GB space
unsigned long sz = sizeof(unsigned char)*1000000000;
unsigned char * m_buffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(sz);

if(m_buffer == NULL)
{
    printf("Memory Allocation failed\n");
}
else
{
    // Protect memory from being swapped
    if(!VirtualLock(m_buffer , sz))
    {
           printf("Memory swap protection failed\n");
    }           
}
```

But the change in Working set fails, and so does the VirtualLock. Malloc does return non-null.

[Edit2]
I have tried also:

```
 unsigned long sz = sizeof(unsigned char)*1000000000;
 LPVOID lpvResult;
 lpvResult = VirtualAlloc(NULL,sz, MEM_PHYSICAL|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOCACHE);
```

But lpvResult is 0, so no luck there either.

Comment: I assume you want Windows, not Window as your tag. I changed for you.

Comment: Yes sorry. Didn't see the typo. It's Windows using Visual Studio.

Comment: Is it possible to disable the swap on a per application basis?

Comment: See `VirtualAlloc` on MSDN for committing and reserving memory.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: It does look similar. They are using .NET however. I am looking at the VirtualLock function.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky I did not notice that the question was for .net, all of the answers are P/Invoke API calls anyway so it is still relevant.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That question is good as a pointer, but after reading some more, there's more to it (its tags might need an adjustment though). It seems I also need to call SetProcessWorkingSetSize and increase the min and max to ensure I can get the pages I need.

Comment: Is it possible to make an array globally 1GB big?

Comment: Nominating for reopen: linked question is not a duplicate.

Comment: I agree myself. I never found the other question and my question raises other issues which I think will be important for those looking for an answer.

Comment: +reopen, SO is too aggressive.

Comment: If your host machine has the memory, you could create a RAM drive, then take the incoming data and "write to file" on the RAM drive. I used to do this for a similar application. Pain was setting up the RAM drive programmically. Once you have that, you can easily open a file in the ram and write to it at memory access speeds.

Comment: @StarPilot: It sounds like what you're suggesting is for Linux. Am I correct?

Comment: You can create RAM DISK in Microsoft land as well. I used to do it back in the MS-DOS days. Let my use my Googlefu to find more info.

Comment: First few results show a freeware product for personal use (commercial for commercial) at: http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk for Windows family to create RAM Disk. So it is definitely been done already. Let's see what else I can turn up.

Comment: @StarPilot: I think this is overkill for what I need. There has to be a way for windows to do it with its own APIs.

Comment: There may be a way to do it with native Windows API. You could always check the open source RAM Driver to see how they do it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [mlock, mlockall, munlock, munlockall](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mlock.2.html) functions in order to prevent pages from being swapped (part of POSIX, also available in MinGW). Unfortunately, I have no experience with Windows but it looks like [VirtualLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does the same thing.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Visual Studio for this particular application but I'll keep these in mind just in case I every try to do the same in MingW or linux.

Comment: My understanding is that `VirtualLock` doesn't *quite* do what you want. It *does* "lock the pages in memory", but I remember reading somewhere that that's *only* for when your process is actually running, not when the threads are paused. When the threads are paused, they may very well be paged out, and paged back in when a thread needs to run again. (I'm not 100% sure about this; it isn't documented in the MSDN documentation, but I'm pretty sure I read it somewhere. Apparently using option 2 as I stated in my answer gets around it, but again, no guarantees.)

Answer (score 4):

I think [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) might get you some of what you want.

This problem really boils down to just writing your own memory manager instead of using CRT function.

Comment: In my case I'm lucky because these are data frames of fixed size and I want to put them all contiguously, so it should be simple to manage. Just need to make sure that memory is allocated and doesn't get moved around.

Comment: I think that you can get away from writing your own memory manager by using malloc + VirtualLock.

Comment: Which option in VirtualAlloc guarantees that the memory won't be paged out?

Comment: Yes, it seems like VirtualLock will do it. I am looking at whether I also need to use SetProcessWorkingSetSize to increase the Working Set. Do you know whether I need to do this?

Comment: I do not see an option in VirtualAlloc to lock the pages. The answer from Vlad with VirtualLock seems the right one. SetProcessWorkingSetSize does also work although it does not guarantee that all pages of the process will never be paged out.

Comment: I see PAGE_NOCACHE is a flag in the protection. I'll give it a try and see if it runs. I'd be interested if there was a way to actually test that it doesn't get cached.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: There must be a way. Look for a Windows alternative to [`getrusage()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) and its hard page faults and swaps counter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the undocumented [`NtLockVirtualMemory`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/Memory%20Management/Virtual%20Memory/NtLockVirtualMemory.html) function with lock option 2 (`LOCK_VM_IN_RAM`); make sure you request and obtain `SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME` privilege first, and be aware that it might not be granted (I'm sure what the group policy defaults the privilege to, but it might very well be granted to nobody).

I suggest using `VirtualLock` as a fallback, and if that fails too, to use `SetProcessWorkingSetSize`. If *that* fails then just let it fail I guess...

See [this link](http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-device-drivers/261194-memory-ordering-flag-state-variables-4.html) for some nice discussion about this. One person says:

> When you specify `LOCK_VM_IN_WSL` flag, you just tell the Balance Set Manager that you don't want some particular page to get swapped to the disk, and ask it to leave this page alone when trimming the working set of the target process. This is just an indication, so that the target page may still get swapped if the system is low on RAM. However, when you specify `LOCK_VM_IN_RAM` flag, you issue a directive to the Memory Manager to treat this page as non-pageable (i.e. do something the driver does when it calls `MmProbeAndLockPages`() in order to lock pages, described by MDL) , so that the page is question is guaranteed to be loaded in RAM all the time.

---

### Edit:

#### Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/06/5924058.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a RAM Disk out of your host's memory. While there is no longer native support for this in the distributed Windows code, you can still find the drivers necessary for free or made available through commercial products. For instance, DRDataRam provides a free driver for personal use and a commercially licensed product for business use at: http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk

There is also ImDisk Virtual Driver available at: http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk It is open sourced and free for commercial use. It is digitally signed with a trusted certificate from Microsoft.

For more information concerning RAM Drives on Windows, check out ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Address Windowing Extensions (AWE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It sounds like it matches the memory constraints you have (emphasis mine):

> AWE uses **physical nonpaged memory** and window views of various portions of this physical memory within a 32-bit virtual address space.